# Return random based off percentage

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure out a way to accomplish this, but I'm running into a wall and I figured I would ask here.

Here is an example:

Let's say I have two objects, food and water, and they have different 'chance' values. One has a 20% chance, one a 40% chance. How would I be able to mathematically add to their total, given that percentage?

```
var food = {
    name:'food',
    total:0,
    chance:0.2
};
var water = {
    name:'water',
    total:0,
    chance:0.4
};
```

This is what I have so far, but this isn't really percentage based. Looking for ways to improve it.

```
function test() {
    var x = parseFloat(Math.random().toFixed(1));

    if(x == food.chance) {
        food.total += 1;
    }
    if(x == water.chance) {
        water.total += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close.

```
function test() {
     var x = parseFloat(Math.random().toFixed(1));

    if(x < food.chance) {
        food.total += 1;
    }
    else if(x < food.chance + water.chance) {
        water.total += 1;
    }
}
```

Two notes:

- In continuous probabilities, you almost never check some random output equals something; just that it's between somethings. Almost by definition, the former is 0.
- This still leaves a 40% that neither happened, FYI.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll also take a look at the linked article. Should be easier searching now knowing what it's called.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```
if ( (x >= 0.0) && (x < food.chance) ) food.total++;
else if ( (x >= food.chance) && (x < (food.chance+water.chance)) water.total++;
```

Comment: This is exactly the same logic as Ami's answer, just written a different way. Incidentally, `0.0 === 0`. ; -)